# Build form with associative array name

Tags: php, html

I need to build a form to output the below $filters array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filterType] => hotelStar
            [filterValue] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [filterType] => hotelStar
            [filterValue] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [filterType] => hotelStar
            [filterValue] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [filterType] => resultLimit
            [filterValue] => 2000
        )

)
```

The form that i have is

```
<form action="output.php" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="filterType[]" value="[hotelStar]3,4,5">
<input type="radio" name="filterType[]" value="[hotelStar]3">
<input type="radio" name="filterType[]" value="[hotelStar]4">
<input type="radio" name="filterType[]" value="[hotelStar]5">
<input type="hidden" name="filterType[]" value="[resultLimit]2000">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The output that i receive is :

```
Array
(
    [filterType] => Array
        (
            [0] => [hotelStar]3
            [1] => [hotelStar]4
            [2] => [hotelStar]5
            [3] => [resultLimit]2000
        )

)
```

But the output isnot the expected one. I have tried almost all posibilities, but i cant find the working one.

Comment: Show us your attempts!

Comment: Please post the output that you get although it's wrong.

Comment: The array index you want has to be part of the form fields _name_, not the _value_.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt would be the following:

Name the items in your form normal, eg.

```
<form action="<?$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="hotelStar3" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="hotelStar4" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="hotelStar5" value="5">
<input type="hidden" name="resultLimit" value="2000">
<button type="submit" name = "submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

In your output.php, assign the values to the array.

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
  $filters = array(
    array('filterType' => 'hotelStars', 'filterValue' => $_GET['hotelStars3']),
    array('filterType' => 'hotelStars', 'filterValue' => $_GET['hotelStars4']),
    array('filterType' => 'hotelStars', 'filterValue' => $_GET['hotelStars5']),
    array('filterType' => 'resultLimit', 'filterValue' => $_GET['resultLimit']));
  print_r($filters);
```

Comment: @em0tic0n Sorry, forgot brackets. Here you go.